# How to calculate date and time before x hours and minutes?

Tags: c#, time, subtraction

I want to find exact date and time that was before x hours and x minutes from now.

For example - today is `2/21/2016 1:15 PM`, and I want to know what was the time before 13 hours and 56 minutes or 73 hours and 34 minutes.
What is the easiest way to do that in C#?

I've found [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby(v=vs.110).aspx), but don't know exactly how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `AddHours()` and `AddMinutes()`.  Also works with negative values to go back in time.

Example:

```
DateTime pastDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-74).AddMinutes(-34);
```

Comment: Alright, thank you guys! And what about exact date e.g. before 72 hours the date is also different?

Comment: Just try it.  It will of course also modify the date.

Comment: @b450005: Do you mean `DateTime.Now.AddHours(-72)`? Please don't forget to upvote answers that helped you and to accept the correct answer. :)

Comment: Yes meant to write 72 :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, you can also use TimeSpan operations on DateTime objects.

Something like

```
DateTime d = ...;
DateTime newDate = d - new TimeSpan(....);
```

Comment: This will not work because new is a resered keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
int d = 0;
int h = -13;
int m = -56;
int s = 0;
DateTime past = DateTime.Now.AddDays(d).AddHours(h).AddMinutes(m).AddSeconds(s);
```

Or, in short:

```
DateTime past = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-13).AddMinutes(-56);
```

This would give you the time 13 hours and 56 minutes ago. Mind the minus for the hours and minutes, they are used to substract a certain amount of time.

Have a look at [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx), and all its methods starting with `Add`.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use [`DateTime.AddXXX` methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that.

For example;

```
var dt1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-13).AddMinutes(-56);
```

or

```
var dt1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-73).AddMinutes(-34);
```

If you wanna take *only* date or time parts of the results, you can use it's [`Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date) or [`TimeOfDay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday) properties.

```
var date = dt1.Date;
```

or

```
var time = dt1.TimeOfDay;
```

Comment: Your very first version did not include any information that the other two answers did not cover. Removed my -1 because you added additional info about Date and TimeOfDay.

Comment: @MarkusWeninger Yeah, thanks to my poor internet connection, it takes 3-4 minutes to edit an answer.